# Cuda atomic operations on unsigned short

Tags: cuda, gpu, atomic

Are there some inbuilt functions in cuda for doing atomic operations on unsigned short or unsigned char?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there are no CUDA atomic intrinsics for `unsigned short` and `unsigned char` data types, or any data type smaller than 32 bits.

However, you could group together two shorts or four chars and perform a 32-bit atomic on them, processing multiple at once (assuming your computation permits this).